# Server Remote Console Stopped working after reboot

Tags: linux, remote-access, console, rsa, ibm

I was working on IBM x3650 M4 Physical server running Red Hat 6.4 with HA LVM. I upgraded the kernel to latest version and reboot it. The server came up just fine and booted with latest kernel.

Then I have to rebuild a custom application rpm which makes use of installed kernel modules. So i rebuilt the source rpm and installed it. It also required reboot.

The server rebooted and came up fine. I was logged in using ssh and also I have the IMM Remote console open to see what's going on while booting.

One of the last step of my task also required reboot but this time the server rebooted and I saw the IMM console got stuck. After five mins or so I did a reboot from the IMM console options and nothing happened.

And to my surprise I tried to login using ssh and it worked so server did reboot fine but somehow the console got stuck.

Now I am unable to reach out to the console home page as well. The IP can be reachable and i can ping it from the same network.

Has anyone encountered such situation before?

The server is present in Remote DataCenter so I don't have direct reach to  it. I can only see that RSA IMM IP is pinging but it's not working via HTTP the usual way.

Thanks,
Sandeep

Comment: Do someone has any info on the above query ?

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue now.

I have tried below but did not help

1. Tried connecting to IMM port via Telnet and SSH but the IMM port did not respond.
2. Installed ASU Utility - It's an IBM tool for managing/controlling RSA/IMM based servers. Tried rebooting IMM using asu commands but did not help
3. Tried impi_tool - did not help

What worked for me:

- Engaged a person on site
- Powered off the server
- Asked that guy to pull power cable and plug them back after 5 minutes.
- Asked him to push the start button

and then only it worked.

So for folks who are or will deal with such situations where you can ping IMM IP but can not reset or log onto it. Power off the server and pull out the power cable to reset the IMM

There is another option too but I did not try that since I decided to pull power cable
The option is to goto BIOS and reset IMM there. but that will also requrie  a server reboot. 
So I thought instead of reboot why don't I power off completely.